# Problems calculating the actual height of web page elements with Javascript and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, pagination

I am modifying some code I found for paginating HTML content into a `div`.  The code is from the jQuery rain site found on this page:

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?HtS47Rzc

The intent of this code is to take a large chunk of HTML, scan the top level child elements, and create a page object for each group of child elements that fit within a desired height (E.g. `400px`).  Once all the pages are built, each page is wrapped in a new `div`.  The problem I'm having is that the calculated pages aren't close to the desired height once rendered to the page.  So instead of each page having a nice block of text that neatly bumps into but does not exceed the bottom of the containing `div`, some pages have text falling far short of the desired page bottom and some exceed the page bottom.  Actually they no longer exceed the page bottom since I added code that scans the pages array after each page has been wrapped with a `div` and sets the container `div` to the maximum `div` height found.

One thought I had is that the wrapping of the `div` was causing the variance so I explicitly added CSS rules to set the margins and padding to `0px`.  That had no effect.  Can anyone tell me how to adjust the code so that the page height calculations work properly?

UPDATE: I'm showing the CSS for the `div` that holds a page and the DIV that contains it.

```
.example{
    background:#FFF;
    width:410px;
    border:1px #000 solid;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px
}
```

The page `div`s all have the class of "page":

```
#content .page {
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Here is my Javascript modified code.  Note, the object being processed by the function is the main `div` that shows the paginated content:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        MyPagination: function (options) {
            var defaults = {
                height: 400,
                fadeSpeed: 400
            };
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            //Creating a reference to the object
            var objContent = $(this);

            // The array of pages we will build.
            var fullPages = new Array();

            // The array of elements for each page, used during pagination calculations.
            var pageElements = new Array();

            // The height for each page, reset after each page is built.
            var height = 0;
            var lastPage = 1;
            var paginatePages;

            // initialization function
            init = function ()
            {
                // Build the array of pages by creating a new page when the sum of the child elements
                //  height values for each page exceeds the desired page height.
                //
                // NOTE:  This is only an approximation.  Haven't figured out why yet.  When the
                //  operation is done there is large variance in the DIV height away from our desired
                //  height, many of them larger than our desired height.
                objContent.children().each(function (i)
                {
                    // Some browsers don't support clientHeight.  In those cases, use offsetHeight.
                    var childHeight = this.clientHeight == 0 ? this.offsetHeight : this.clientHeight;

                    // If the height of all the children in the page elements array exceeds the desired
                    //  page height, start a new page.
                    if (height + childHeight > options.height)
                    {
                        // Start a new page.
                        fullPages.push(pageElements);

                        // Reset the page elements array by initializing it to a new array.
                        pageElements = new Array();

                        // Reset the page height accumulatore. for the next page.
                        height = 0;
                    }

                    // Accumulate the child element's height into the height aggregator variable.
                    height += childHeight;

                    // Add the child element to the child elements array for the page currently being built.
                    pageElements.push(this);
                });

                if (height > 0) {
                    fullPages.push(pageElements);
                }

                // wrapping each full page
                // $(fullPages).wrap("<div class='page'></div>");

                // Wrapping each full page with a DIV.  Give the DIV an ID that contains the page number.
                $(fullPages).wrap(
                        function (ndx) {
                            return "<div class='page' name='pages' id='page_" + (ndx + 1) + "'></div>"
                        });

                // Find the DIV with the maximum height.
                var maxDivHeight = 0;

                for (var ndx = 1; ndx <= fullPages.length; ndx++) {
                    var pageN = document.getElementById('page_' + ndx);

                    // Some browsers don't support clientHeight.  In those cases, use offsetHeight.
                    var divHeight = pageN.clientHeight == 0 ? pageN.offsetHeight : pageN.clientHeight;

                    if (divHeight > maxDivHeight)
                        maxDivHeight = divHeight;
                }

                // Set the height of the content DIV to the maximum height we found plus a little padding.
                objContent.height(maxDivHeight);

                // hiding all wrapped pages
                objContent.children().hide();

                // making collection of pages for pagination
                paginatePages = objContent.children();

                // show first page
                showPage(lastPage);

                // draw controls
                showPagination($(paginatePages).length);
            };

            // update counter function
            updateCounter = function (i) {
                $('#page_number').html(i);
            };

            // show page function
            showPage = function (page) {
                i = page - 1;
                if (paginatePages[i]) {

                    // hiding old page, display new one
                    $(paginatePages[lastPage]).fadeOut(options.fadeSpeed);
                    lastPage = i;
                    $(paginatePages[lastPage]).fadeIn(options.fadeSpeed);

                    // and updating counter
                    updateCounter(page);
                }
            };

            // perform initialization
            init();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Did you take into account that you might be altering the layout, and thus breaking some CSS that were applied originally?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - Yes.  That's why I added the CSS rules to specify no margins and no padding.  I also have been doing a lot of inspecting of the computed styles with the Chrome debugger and have not (yet) seen anything that could interfere.  I have added the CSS for the DIVs that hold a page to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use getBouningClientRect on your element. This will give you the position and size of that element:

```
var clientRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

And now you can get the size and position:

```
var leftPos = clientRect.left;
var topPos = clientRect.top;
var width = clientRect.width;
var height = clientRect.height;
```

Hope this helps!

Here is a link to more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect